Usage of それなりの体制で in this sentence?

なのに、ああいうことになったんだ。敵さんの意図も正体も分からない以上、こっちもそれなりの体制で現場に臨むべきなんじゃねえのか」

After a recent failed mission, the characters are discussing that for the next missions, they should be careful and watch out for their partners. Then a character adds this.
The first part is akin to "Given we don't know the enemies' intention and their true nature"
I understand he's saying it like... we should be careful or whatever but I'm a bit stumbled on the nuance of それなりの体制で. I assume で is "by the way of" nuance.

X なり does not only correspond to "the way of X" or "as much as X can do" but also, in a sense, something opposite: "deserving X", "reflecting X", or "adjusting to X". 体制 is a word that broadly refers to "systems to organize people for some purposes".
So, in this context, それなりの体制で can be translated like: "with a due level of setup" or "with enough preparation/organization to face it (the unidentified enemy)".
